# can't resize Watch columns in VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

After floating the Watch 1 pane, resizing its columns, then returning it to its original docked position, all the columns are jammed together at the left end of the pane. When I try to drag any of the column dividers, the dragging appears to work while I hold the mouse button down but, once I release the button, the new location doesn't take.

I have tried re-floating the pane and changing the columns so that they will fit within the space needed when it is docked but that doesn't help. Unfortunately, it seems as if VS has a separate set of column positions for its docked state so changing them in the floating state doesn't help.

Comment: That's not a common problem.  The state of the columns are stored in a file, maybe there's something wrong with it.  Try deleting the hidden `.vs/projname/v14/.suo` file.

Comment: Thanks. That seemed to clear it. Either that or restarting VS.